# Small .iso file becomes huge when burned to DVD

Tags: dvd, iso-image, dvd-burning, mkisofs

I created an `.iso` with:

> mkisofs -o isofile.iso file

The iso was small, about 300KB

And then I burned it with:

> cdrskin dev=/dev/sr0 -v padsize=300k isofile.iso

And to my surprise, when I took out the DVD, about one fifth of the DVDs area was written to, which seems rather excessive considering the file was only about 300KB, and the DVD had space for about 2GB.

If you do the math, and assume that the DVD has 2GB, and one fifth of that space was used, you get that more than 300MB of data were written to the DVD. That is about thousand times more than the file size, and hence probably not due to padding, blocksizes or similar reasons.

Why does this happen then?

Comment: An ISO file is not just a container with data in it. It contains a file of content that points to data blocks. It is a known copy protection method to make inaccuracies in the table of content, having files point to larger chunks of data without there actually be the need for that data. Some image burning tools literally write data in order to make sure that toc works, which can result in a dvd giving the error: insufficient space to burn.

Comment: This seems plausible... can I manually inspect the iso somehow to check?

Comment: actually I now tried with a different much larger iso (2MB memtest iso of Ubuntu) and got the same result, so maybe a bug in cdrskin?

Comment: Ok so now i simulated burning the dvd several times, and it takes clearly too long for the amount of data given, furthermore cdrskin says it is working post-track, so i suppose its an issue of cdrskin and that it continues writing some stuff after all data has been written, but why?

Comment: It could just be a bug in the software. Maybe see if cdrskin has a support forum and if other users also have this problem, if not, contact their support if there is or try other software

Comment: of course installing another command line tool is the obvious solution! Thanks, unironically did not see that... Will install an alternative and see whether such issues continue to happen...

Comment: Technically, its not the solution, but the next step in troubleshooting. :) but glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running cdrskin without option -multi on a DVD-R or a sequential DVD-RW
causes post-track activity long enough for writing 1 GB.

The MMC-5 specification for command CLOSE TRACK SESSION mentions a
minimal radius of 30 millimeters of the recorded area. That's about 1 GB
of data. With DVD-R[W] the decision to pad up is left to the drive.
With DVD+R it is possible to chose between two close functions.
One of them is:

6.3.3.4.4 Close Function 101b: Finalize the Disc with minimal radius
"[...] In order to assure maximum interchange compatibility with read only
devices, Guard Zone 2 shall be recorded to a device defined PSN that
approximates a disc radius of 30 mm. Suggested value: 70DE0h (462 304)."
(Table 49: Guard Zone 2 is at the end of the Lead-Out of a DVD+R.)

libburn underneath cdrskin uses this function when it closes a DVD+R.

Other software might use the other close function, which does not pad up:

6.3.3.4.5 Close Function 110b: Finalize the Disc

Whatever, no space is wasted by padding if the disc gets closed anyway.

If i add option -multi to the cdrskin run on a sequential DVD-RW, then the
post-track activity lasts not that long. The first session is inflated to
about 128 MiB. The Next Writable Address is even higher by another 56 MiB.
A second session is done quite quickly and not inflated beyond the
desired padding. The gap to the Next Writable Address is only 12 MiB.
If i omit -multi with the third session, no long post-track activity is
to see. The finally used up capacity of the DVD is about 200 MiB.
Looks like the drive (ASUS BW-16D1HT 3.10) did not feel the need for
filling up to 1 GB with a multi-session DVD-RW.

Comment: Seems like you got it man.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the width of the written area in the radial direction, keep in mind that the relationship between the written width and the amount of data is not linear. The capacity of a mini-DVD of 8 cm diameter is only about a third of a full-size 12 cm DVD. So the outer 2 cm of radius of the full-size DVD must contain about 2/3 of the data.

Another factor is that each burn session needs its lead-in and lead-out areas, whose sizes are independent of the size of the burned data. I don't have any firm numbers for those at hand, but I would expect that when burning a 300kB ISO to a DVD, the width of the written area would be dominated by the requirements for lead-in and lead-out.

Comment: I already considered the area, and about one fifth of the area was written to. also, with other software on another device i burned much more data on much less area. So it must have something to do with the concrete way I did this burn. (But I dont know what)